# updateStatusCallback not defined on facebook examble of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

So, I'm trying to integrate my html with facebook, add facebook login, share, that sort of stuff, but I'm finding a problem. Have searched here and could find the solution for most, but not this one.

It says on the JavaScript console, after I load the html:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateStatusCallback is not defined.
```

The code is small, so I'll paste it here.

```
<html>

<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Testes</title>
    <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
        FB.init({
        appId: '383086835168967',
        });     
      $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
      FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback); <-- Error ocurring on this line. More specicly, on updateStatusCallback. -->
  });
});

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Code found at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/)

Comment: u need to define the updateStatusCallback function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `updateStatusCallback` logic is left to the developer. You should do:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(){
   alert('Status updated!!');
   // Your logic here
});
```

Or leave the code as you have it now, but adding this:

```
function updateStatusCallback(){
   alert('Status updated!!');
   // Your logic here
}
```